# $filter by multiple object properties not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I try to filter array of objects by multiple fields. My initial code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in $data | filter: { package: { cycleId: filterOptions.cycle, status: filterOptions.status }}">
```

does not work. Interestingly, first filter expression works (changing filterOptions.cycle filters correctly) but when I add filterOptions.status something is wrong. It filters randomly, I can not find a pattern, but for sure is does not filter my $data array by package.cycleId AND package.status.

But then, when I changed filtering to this filter chaing:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in $data | filter: { package: { cycleId: filterOptions.cycle } } | filter: { package: { status: filterOptions.status } }">
```

everything works as expected.

What is wrong with my first code snippet? I'm asking because on AngularJS page:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter (I'm using AngularJS v1.2.14), filtering say that

> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on
>   objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"}
>   predicate will return an array of items which have property name
>   containing "M" and property phone containing "1".

Comment: Which Angularjs version are you using? I was hoping 1.2.x solved this issue..